# Are these lines grammatically correct?

Tags: meaning-in-context, grammaticality, lyrics

Lines from One Direction Song Steal my Girl:

> I don't exist
>
> If I don't have her
>
> The sun doesn't shine,
>
> The world doesn't turn,
>
> Alright (alright)

Are these lines grammatically correct? What do they mean? What kind of conditional sentence it is I can't make it out.

Comment: Song lyrics do not need to be grammatically correct— as with poetry, grammar is secondary to rhythm, mood, and other artistic considerations. Songs are meant to be heard, not read, and pop songs in particular may simply be gibberish.

Comment: It's hard to understand which "sentence" you are asking about here. Please use the [edit] link to tell us.

Comment: @choster Do you mean to say I've wasted all those years spent pondering the grammatical construction _"Papa ooh mow mow"_?

Comment: @P.E.Dant , Bird *is* the word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are grammatically correct. The spelling of "Alright" might raise some eyebrows, but this is a traditionally correct alternative to "All right".

The language is figurative, which is common in songs (and more generally in poetry). I'll assume you have no difficulty in the literal meaning of "I don't exist, if I don't have her." Figuratively, the singer means that being this girl's boyfriend is the most important thing to him: *If she is not my girlfriend then things like the sun shining, the world revolving or me existing are nothing to me.*

The first and second lines for a complete sentence. The third and fourth lines each have an implied "(If I don't have her) the sun doesn't shine." It is implied by the context.

Comment: Also, the force or meaning of ***if** I don't have her* is ***since** I don't have her*